# Declaring a CGFloat on the fly?

Tags: swift

In the loop below I don't understand the syntax of `CGFloat(i)` nor do I know what to look up to learn more.

```
  for i in 0...2 {

        newX = viewWidth / 2 + viewWidth * CGFloat(i)

  }
```

I am familiar with code in a loop that looks simply like

`newX = viewWidth / 2 + viewWidth * i`

I understand we are declaring the type of `i` but I've never seen it like this before. What is this called and where can I read more about this?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgfloat for the various init methods of `CGFloat`

Comment: Does this only apply to CGFloat?

Comment: No, all integer and floating point types have a long list of init methods. If you cmd-click on a type in Xcode then you should find them quickly.

Comment: `i` is `Int` and you convert that to a `CGFloat` value using its [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgfloat/1456586-init). Since you don't have do that conversion for this specific case, it is mostly needed to do that when you are doing calculations using two different types.